# conda conflicting with msys2 mingw-w64 gcc installation

Tags: windows, gcc, conda, mingw-w64, msys2

On Windows, I'm using `python` installed with `conda` and `gcc`.
So far, I had an old `mingw-w64` installed with some installer (I couldn't retrieve the exact origin).
`mingw-w64` was added to the system `PATH`.
When developing in C++, I'm compiling using `python` scripts and `cmake`.
It all worked fine but I was stuck with an old gcc version (8.1) and updating mingw-w64 isn't really a piece of cake (can't find anymore a clean installer).

Thus I wanted to go for a "more modern" way to manage `gcc` and installed `msys2` plus the `mingw-w64` `gcc` package provided by `msys2`.

Now, compiling a program in a shell without `conda` is just working as expected but as I activate `conda`, `gcc` crashes silently when compiling.

I see that activating `conda` is adding `[...]\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin` to my system `PATH` but I can't understand why it would have worked with the old `gcc` install and not the new one.

How can I resolve this conflict?

[EDIT] `cmake` error

with `cmake --debug-trycompile .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc`
I've got

> debug trycompile on
> -- The C compiler identification is unknown
> -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> CMake Debug Log at [...]/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake:57 (try_compile):
> Executing try_compile (CMAKE_C_ABI_COMPILED) in:
> [...]/build/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-41abgu
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> [...]/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:26 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ABI)
> CMakeLists.txt:47 (project)
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
> -- Check for working C compiler: [...]/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe
> CMake Debug Log at [...]/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:56 (try_compile):
> Executing try_compile (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS) in:
> [...]/build/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-dsx3w6
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> CMakeLists.txt:47 (project)
> -- Check for working C compiler: [...]/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe - broken
> CMake Error at [...]/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
> The C compiler
> "[...]/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe"
> is not able to compile a simple test program.
> It fails with the following output:
> Change Dir: '[...]/build/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-dsx3w6'
> Run Build Command(s): [...]/msys64/mingw64/bin/cmake.exe -E env VERBOSE=1 [...]/msys64/ucrt64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile cmTC_ecb19/fast      
> [...]/msys64/ucrt64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_ecb19.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_ecb19.dir/build
> mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory '[...]/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-dsx3w6'
> Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_ecb19.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
> [...]\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_ecb19.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c [...]/build\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-dsx3w6\testCCompiler.c
> mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmTC_ecb19.dir\build.make:77: CMakeFiles/cmTC_ecb19.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
> mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory '[...]/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-dsx3w6'
> mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_ecb19/fast] Error 2
> CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> CMakeLists.txt:47 (project)
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[EDIT] `gcc`crash error:
When running in `cmd` windows instead of a `powershell`, I can have an error popup when `gcc` crashes:

> as.exe entry point not found
> entry point for procedure zstd_compressStream2 could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\<path to msys2 install>\ucrt64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\13.2.0\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\as.exe

Comment: Weird. PATH can cause issues when you don't have the necessary DLLs next to executables and rely on them being in PATH, but MSYS2 doesn't do that.

Comment: What if you install `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zlib` in msys2 and try again?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thx but I couldn't test as I eventually uninstall conda and go for a fresh miniconda install. Previous install seemed broken and failed to update.